# SignalR - get button's element ID

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am creating a reconcile application for an EDRMs. The application reconciles the EDRMs with another website so that the EDRMs has the same folder structure as the website.

Once the reconcile button has been clicked, the `results` page will show all the folder paths that exist in only one of the systems. Then the user has to click around the website and EDRMs to find out why they don't reconcile and possibly add the paths manually.

This is annoying and most people don't bother and leave it to someone else so we have decided to add a bit more intelligence into the application. On the results page there is a button next to each path that we can create automatically for them. Each button element has a unique ID.

`

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="../00100001.htm" target="_blank">FUNCTION/ACTIVITY</a></td>
                        <td>
                                <button id="FUNCTION/ACTIVITY" name="FUNCTION/ACTIVITY" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Create</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

`

What I need these buttons to do is when clicked, send the ID of the button to signalR so I can create the path in the system. Below is what my current javascript looks like.

`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // initialize the connection to the server
        var reconcileListen = $.connection.reconcilehub;

        // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
        $('button').click(
        function () {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                var ticket = getCookie('ticket');
                var successmessage = $("#successmessage");
                successmessage.addClass('hidden');
                reconcileListen.server.recon();
            });
        });

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

`

I have attempted to use `onClick="reconcile(this.id)"` in the button's element, and I am still thinking this might be the way to go, however, I have not had success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but surely you just need to get the event.target.id in the click event?

```
$('button').click(
        function () {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                var id = event.target.id;
                var ticket = getCookie('ticket');
                var successmessage = $("#successmessage");
                successmessage.addClass('hidden');
                reconcileListen.server.recon();
            });
        });
```

Comment: I was TOTALLY over complicating things. I did have to add `event` as a parameter for the function after the click otherwise it would come as undefined on the first button click for some reason. Thanks so much!